# Laravel get sums from models with two and more joins

Tags: php

I want to get the sum of prices from contract table and sum of transactions together connected  to user id. And how can i use where in this.

Table Contracts:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id":97,
    "price":"100"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id":97,
    "price":"200"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id":97,
    "price":"300"
  }
]
```

Table Transactions:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "user_id":97,
    "sum":"100"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "user_id":97,
    "sum":"200"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "user_id":97,
    "sum":"300"
  }
]
```

My query:

```
$query = User::where([
    ['contracts_sum', '<', 'transactions_sum'],
])
->join('contracts', 'contracts.user_id', '=','users.id')
->join('transactions', 'users.id', '=','transactions.user_id')
->groupBy(['users.id'])
->select(
    'users.id', 'users.name',
    DB::raw('SUM(contracts.price) AS contracts_sum'),
    DB::raw('SUM(transactions.sum) AS transactions_sum'),
)
->get();
```

But this variant returns sum multiplied to count of transactions table rows like this:

```
[
  {
    "id":97,
    "name":"JOHN",
    "contracts_sum":"1800",
    "transactions_sum":"1800"
  }
]
```

But i would like to get the data in this kind of form:

```
[
  {
    "id":97,
    "name":"JOHN",
    "contracts_sum":"600",
    "transactions_sum":"600"
  }
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323925/mysql-sum-function-in-multiple-joins

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to make use of laravel's relation feature, as it would make it a lot easier.

```php
class User
{
  public function transactions()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'user_id', 'id');
  }

  public function contracts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Contract::class, 'user_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

Then, in your controller, you could do the following:

```php
$user = User::where('id', 97)
  ->withSum('contracts', 'price')
  ->withSum('transactions', 'sum')
  ->get();

return [
  'id' => $user->id,
  'name' => $user->name,
  'contracts_sum' => $user->transactions_sum_sum,
  'transactions_sum' => $user->contracts_sum_price
];
```

Not only does this look a lot cleaner, the query will be more efficient as well. More information on the aggregate functions can be found in [the laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions).

Comment: Thank you for answer, and how can i use where in this exaple

Comment: @iskandarovismoil, what do you mean? I included the where clause on the first line of the controller code. It's a bit simplified, but you could replace the where clause with your original where clause for an identical result.

Comment: Yes, but it turns out I forgot to add to the question that I need to compare these two amounts, for example where('contracts_sum_price', '>', 'transactions_sum_sum')